# Drawing (X,Y,Z) float points in pictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, drawing

I have an array that contains 3D float points. How could I depict them in PictureBox in c# environment?

Example)
        lets say we have array called X:

```
   X=[0, 0, 0; 0.48, -0.88, 0.09; -1.06, 0.55, 0.9; -0.65, 1.5, -1.44; 1.1, 0.59,
-1.11;0.76, 0.86, -0.52; -1.08, -0.28, 0.55; 1.47, -1.21, 0.14; 1.42, -2.15, 0.71; -0.64,  
1.87, 2.4;2.32, -2.44, 2.02; 2.25, -2.56, -3.03; 2.35, 2.65, -1.5; 0.23, -2.25, 2.78; 2.47,  
-3.12,  -1.91; 2.27, 1.37, -3.05; 2.3, 1.9, -1.29; -1.77, -0.51, 2.33];  

    X1= [0,0,0]  
    X2=[0.48, -0.88, 0.09]  
    X3=[-1.06, 0.55, 0.9] ...
```

Now these points have to be shown on a picturebox with connected together sequentially.

Comment: winforms doesn't support 3D. if you need 3D capabilities you have to use WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can't plot 3D points on picturebox because winforms doesn't provide functionality to pot 3D poits directly for that you can use WPF which support 3D. If you have the knowledge of computer graphics then you can do. Use the algorithm to "Project a 3D world co-ordinates into 2D perspective or parallel projection". Here is an example with source code and complete explanation you can try it http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com/2012/03/projecting-3d-world-co-ordinates-into.html

Comment: Could I use this for winforms or I should convert all my code to wpf?

Comment: You can use this algorithm for winforms.

Comment: @farzinparsa you can integrate WPF content into winforms by using an `ElementHost`, but if I were you, I'd drop winforms immediately. It is a dinousaur technology which is completely unable to deal with today's UI needs. Also, the present/future of Windows Applications (with WinRT) is XAML, which is what WPF uses as well.